# IBM WAS7.x to IBM MQ 8

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

We have application which is running in IBM WAS 7.x and using IBM MQ 7.x. We are planning to upgrade IBM MQ 7.x to 8.x without migrating WAS.We are using Java 6 compiled application and planning to upgrade to Java 7.

I have below Questions for the same.

1. Can IBM WAS 7.x can connect to MQ 8 without upgrading WAS ?
2. Do we need to do anything on WAS 7.x to support Java 7 ?

Any other things need to take care for MQ up-gradation ?

Regards
Subbanarasa Reddy

Answer (score 1):

WAS V7 (via the WMQ V7.0.1 JMS RA component that is included in the product) can connect to any IBM MQ queue manager, including V8 and V9 queue managers.

However, I don't believe that WAS V7 supports a Java 7 runtime.

If you must use Java 7, you should look to migrate to WAS V8.5 or V9.